# Get Checkbox states from python script imbedded in another script

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I am trying to open a separate window from a Tkinter Gui in Python 2.7. The new window had checkboxes, and based on the check box states, I intend to have a button to run some tasks. My problem is that when I imbed the script for the new window and check boxes into my existing pythons script, the variable states of the check boxes always come out as "0." When I run the script for the check boxes by itself, everything works... Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tempfile

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")
root.geometry("200x225")

def NewWindow():
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Select Unit Load Components")
    master.geometry("400x500")

    var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
    var2 = Tkinter.IntVar()
    var3 = Tkinter.IntVar()
    var4 = Tkinter.IntVar()
    var5 = Tkinter.IntVar()
    var6 = Tkinter.IntVar()

    def var_states():
        print("FX: %d, FY: %d, FZ: %d, MX: %d, MY: %d, MZ: %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(),var4.get(), var5.get(), var6.get()))

    Checkbutton(master, text="FX", variable=var1).grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="FY", variable=var2).grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="FZ", variable=var3).grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="MX", variable=var4).grid(row=1,column=4, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="MY", variable=var5).grid(row=1,column=5, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="MZ", variable=var6).grid(row=1,column=6, sticky=W)

    Button(master, text='Show', command=var_states).grid(row=3, sticky=W, pady=4)
    mainloop()

Bttn1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Open Sub Window", command = NewWindow)
Bttn1.pack(side = TOP,padx=10,pady=5)

Bttn3=Tkinter.Button(root, text='Exit', command = root.quit)
Bttn3.pack(side = TOP,padx=50,pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pretty sure you should only run mainloop once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've got another WM (`root = tkinter.Tk()` and `master = Tk()`).
You may use: `master = tkinter.TopLevel(…)`
And, of course, only one mainloop.